# Accessing left side menu Items without Database hit in getting the content

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, struts2

I have to click the left side menu items and without db clicking, it needs to display static contents without using if else .

Say suppose, take the example of http://www.askganesha.com/ when we click any link on the left side menu, content is displayed in the body. That part i have done using struts2 action wild pattern usage. while displaying the content in jsp, i have used if else tags, but i am not satisfied with what i have done. I want to apply a design pattern such that no if else is used and something like putting these left menu items in arraylist and display.

thanks & regards

swapna

Comment: db clicking ? O_o BTW start posting a minimal sample code of what you have done. However, you should probably look at Tiles for this

Comment: Hi Andrea Ligios, i have used tiles with struts2, but thing is that all the left hand side links are all coming under one action (used wild card pattern in struts2). But When displaying the message for each click i am using if else condition for left side menu items, which i suppose not a good one.

Comment: We can't figure out your code, please post a sample of it

Comment: all the left side menu items i have given one common action as hello-* using struts2. if user clicks any link on the left side menu say suppose, clicked a link name health, then action will be hello-health.do and with the help of struts2 i can able to retrieve the health . Similarly if the user clicks on the link called wealth, then the action will be hello-wealth and i can able to retrieve the id wealth. Now like that if 20 items are there on the left menu then based on the id (like health or wealth) , i am using if(health) display health info, else if (wealth) display wealth info.